# Meaning of míng

Tags: character-identification

I'm new to Chinese as well as this forum. I would like to know what this means:
[image]

I know it's pronounced míng, and I also know that the Ming Dynasty once ruled china. Does this also have some other meaning in Chinese, that is not a proper noun?

Comment: Ming dynasty is not the same character: 明 (the character in the photo is 名).

Comment: Don't leave the OP hanging. Put her out of her misery :)

Comment: As a noun, it means name. If it is a verb, it means to describe.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the character "名" appears alone, it generally means "name" or "given name" (by the way, "surnames" in Chinese is "姓", and Chinese name consists of a surname and a given name, so "person's name" in Chinese is "姓名")

If 名 appears with other character, it will have different meanings depending on the context, e.g., a classifier (三名老师, means "three (of) teachers"), fame (名声), famous (闻名), describe (不可名状)...